# "ValueExpression Map" of a JSF component

Tags: jsf

I'm storing value expressions in a JSF component with the f:attribute tag, e.g.:

```
<h:inputText ...>
  <f:attribute name="myId1" value="#{bean.prop1}" />
  <f:attribute name="myId2" value="#{bean.prop2}" />
  <f:attribute name="myId3" value="#{bean.prop3}" />
</h:inputText>
```

Is there a way to access all of those value expressions programmatically? (without knowlegde of the names myId1, myId2,...)

Section 9.4.2 of the JSF 2.1 specification says that those values are stored "in the component’s ValueExpression Map". 
That's the only occurrence of the term "ValueExpression Map" in the complete spec.
How do I access that map?

In the UIcomponent's Method getValueExpression() of the Jboss/Mojarra implementation the map

```
getStateHelper().get(UIComponentBase.PropertyKeys.bindings)
```

is used to obtain a *single* value expression.

I guess that map is a super set of the "ValueExpression Map"?
Can I be sure that all implementations and all inherited (standard) components use that map to store ValueExpressions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In *theory* you should be able to see them all by [`UIComponent#getAttributes()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uicomponent#getAttributes()):

```
var attributes = component.getAttributes();

for (var entry : attributes.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf("name=%s, value=%s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

However, that doesn't work the way as you'd expect. It only returns static attributes. This does not seem to ever going to be fixed/implemented. See also [Mojarra issue 640](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/640). I do however agree that the [javadoc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uicomponent#getAttributes()) needs further clarification on that.

I'd suggest to stick to attribtues with predefinied prefix and an incremental numerical suffix, like as you've presented in your example. You can just collect them as follows:

```
var attributes = component.getAttributes();
var values = new ArrayList<Object>();

for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    var name = "myId" + i;
    var value = attributes.get(name);
    if (value == null && component.getValueExpression(name) == null) break;
    values.add(value);
}

System.out.println(values);
```

Comment: I don't think the specification allows storage of f:attribute-values like above in the attributes-map.

Mojarra doesn't.

Have you tested your code above? Which implementation are you using?

Comment: Huh? Why do you think that? All of component's attributes are in there, see also the linked javadoc: *"Return a mutable Map representing the attributes (and properties, see below) associated wth this UIComponent, keyed by attribute name (which must be a String)"*. This works that way since JSF 1.0.

Comment: 9.4.2 of the spec says: "...call the isLiteralText() method on the argument value. If it returns true, store the value in the component’s attribute Map under the name derived above. If it returns false, store the ValueExpression in the component’s ValueExpression Map under the name derived above."

Also, I have testet it and the attribute-map doesn't contain them.

Comment: The attrbute map also maps through to the value expression map. I've always used it that way in combination with validators and converters and I've never had problems with getting them. Perhaps you're getting them at the wrong moment or the `#{bean}` is lost at the point the attribute value is to be evaluated. An SSCCE from your side would be helpful to understand how you're trying to use them.

Comment: Check the source code of `UIComponentBase$AttributesMap` in Mojarra and you'll see that it obtains attributes from the value expression map.

Comment: Oh right, when you're iterating over the map's entryset, it's not there. But when you manually request it by `attributes.get("name")`, then it's there. I didn't expect that as well, but I've also always used the way as demonstrated in 2nd part of my answer (because the 1st part is pretty clumsy in real world applications anyway). I've for the sake of clariness removed the 1st part of my answer. Sorry about that and thanks for letting me experience myself that it doesn't work that way!

Comment: Yes, if know the key name I can access it. (I then could also use the method getValueExpression() to directly obtain the value expression.) My question was how to to obtain a list of keys.

Comment: I understand, I looked around in the API and I'm afraid there's no API-provided way to get keys of unknown value expressions. I've peeked through several JSF issue documents; this is been acknowledged but it doesn't look like that it would ever be implemented. A good starting point is [issue 636](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-636). I think your best bet is really to use predefinied attribues names with an incremental index. That's also what I've always used for extra information which is to be passed to custom validators/converters.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the answer given by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) might be to use nested facets or UIParameter components. Facets can be retrieved as a map using [getFacets](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getFacets%28%29) but you probably need to put an additional UIOutput inside each facet to access its value expression.

Nested [UIParameters](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIParameter.html) can be accessed by iterating over the components children and checking for `instanceof UIParameter`. UIParameters have `name` and `value` attributes and so could be easily converted to a map.

I have used parameters in a custom component, but I'm not sure how a standard UIInput like in your example reacts to these.

Answer (score 0):

BalusC is right. UIComponent#getAttributes().get(name) gets values from both places - at first from attributes map and then if not found from "value expression map". To put some value you have to call UIComponent#setValueExpression(name, ValueExpression). If value is literal, it gets stored into the attribute map, otherwise into the "value expression map". Everything is ok then.